# How to keep pop up open until it has focus in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, controltemplate, eventtrigger

I am having following XAML for showing a popup on mouse enter event of a text box and close the popup on the mouse leave event of textbox. So, when I try to go to popup then mouse leave event is called and popup is closed. So what I want popup should not be closed if I am having focus on the popup rather popup should be closed if I have clicked on the popup or mouse is not over pop up.

Note: But popup should be closed on mouse leave if I am not having focus on popup.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Control VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="MyText"></TextBox>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup" PopupAnimation="Fade" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Border Background="Red">
                                <TextBlock>Test Popup Content</TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter" SourceName="MyText">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True"/>
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave" SourceName="MyText">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please don't use all bold text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add mouseenter and mouseleave event for popup also same as textbox

```
                  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter" SourceName="Popup">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave" SourceName="Popup">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Popup.IsOpen)">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do this is to bind a `bool` value to the `Popup.IsOpen` property. You can still set this to true in your `MouseEnter` handler, but you can choose when you set it to false:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but actually I dont want to use a property of ViewModel rather I want to do all the magic via XAML itself